# EDI 832 Input table(s)

Tags: edi

I am looking for suggestions/examples on how to create input SQL table(s) to use for loading data into and an EDI 832 format.   I have tried using a single table to load my EDI mapping software however I have ran into snags in elements such as the DTM or N1 elements where you can have more that one entry. You can have a DTM element for Effective Date and Expiration date and each of those are a separate line in the 832 file.   Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

EdiFabric's templates are compliant with Entity Framework, so if you are using .NET the library can create the database structure automatically for 832 or any other X12\EDIFACT transaction. You can use the trial to create the database.

EdiFabric is a commercial .NET product and I work there.